# How to define a custom connector in JointJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, node-modules, jointjs

I'm attempting to define a custom connector in JointJS in Vue.  Though I don't think this is really a JointJS issue or a Vue issue, but rather my lack of understanding of how Javascript modules work in this context...

I have this code, which seems to match the docs (https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v3.3/joint.html#connectors.custom):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
let joint = Vue.joint;

joint.connectors = joint.connectors || {};

joint.connectors.CloudConflictConnector = function(sourcePoint, targetPoint, vertices, args)  
{
...
}
```

Note that Vue.joint is created as a plugin, this way:

```
const Joint = {
    install: function (Vue) {
        let joint = { g, dia, layout, linkTools, V };

        Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$joint', { value: joint });
        Vue.joint = Vue.prototype.$joint;
    }
};
Vue.use(Joint);
```

But when I later attempt to use this connector, `findPath()` in JointJS throws an error that the connector doesn't exist.  The issue appears to be that in `findPath`, it's importing the connectors module from the npm package.  That module obviously doesn't have anything I added to the `Vue.joint.connectors` property.

If I try to add the function to the module more directly, I get a 'Object is not extensible' error.  For example doing something like this in the plugin instead:

```
import * as connectors from 'jointjs/src/connectors/index.mjs';

const Joint = {
    install: function (Vue) {
        let joint = { g, dia, layout, linkTools, V, connectors };
        joint.connectors.customConnector = ...;

        Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$joint', { value: joint });
        Vue.joint = Vue.prototype.$joint;
    }
};
Vue.use(Joint);
```

So I guess the question is how does one properly add a property to a module export in a way that other code that imports the module directly can still see it?  I think outside Vue, this would all just work because `joint` would be a global variable (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is the plugin creates a new `joint` object, which is missing the original import's `connectors` property.

However, I believe the plugin should keep the original import and setup the custom connector on that:

```js
export default {
  install(app) {
    const joint = require('jointjs')
    addCustomConnector(joint)

    app.prototype.$joint = joint
    app.joint = joint
  }
}

function addCustomConnector({ connectors }) {
  connectors.CloudConflictConnector = (sourcePoint, targetPoint, vertices, args) => {
    //...
  }
}
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-contrib/vue-jointjs-demo)

Comment: Yes - switching from importing the individual pieces of JointJS to importing the whole package (in my case -- import * as joint from 'jointjs') solved the issue.  Thanks!